# On linux, is there a way to record the ports a program tries to communicate over?

Tags: linux, firewall, linux-networking, port, kerberos

**Problem**: I am trying to determine which ports to open for specific programs

I have a number of programs that need to access services on remote hosts, but I don't know which ports they are trying to use for the purpose. Rather than opening the firewall up to `0-1024` (or `0-65k`), I would like to identify which ports a program uses while it runs.

The first program to check is `kinit`. From the [documentation](https://uit.stanford.edu/service/kerberos/firewalls) I gather that I need to open port `88` for inbound udp traffic and port `88` for outbound tcp and udp traffic. But this does not seem to be enough, as the program responds with

`kinit: Resource temporarily unavailable while getting initial credentials`

Opening up all ports results in a correct authentication flow for `kinit`:

```
Using default cache: /tmp/krb5cc_16381
Using principal: *****@******.******.***
Password for *****@******.******.***:
Authenticated to Kerberos v5
```

I know about how to use `lsof`, `netstat` and `ss` for retrieving the open ports for processes that bind for longer duration of periods to ports, but especially `kinit` seems to elude this listing, even when used together with a tool such as `watch`.

**Edit**: The accepted answer immediately showed me the culprit: DNS;

```
strace -e trace=connect kinit <user>@<kdc>
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("<kdc_ip>")}, 16) = 0
```

Opening this port fixed the problem with Kerberos

Comment: What programs are they? Do they have config files?

Comment: why don't you just log dropped packets with iptables or firewalld?. Also make sure to check this link from Kerberos MIT to configure your firewall: https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.5/krb5-1.5.4/doc/krb5-admin/Configuring-Your-Firewall-to-Work-With-Kerberos-V5.html. Also of course make sure you allow ports for udp.

Comment: @NasirRiley: in principle any program that does network traffic, but in this particular case I selected kinit because of its characteristics as a program that is not long running

Comment: @LukasRäpple: Thats a good suggestion that wasn't obvious to me, so thanks. I think it is similar to the answer given by @cscracker but the `strace` approach worked better for me and was simpler to use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try strace:

```
strace -e trace=connect your_program with arguments
```

Here is an example output:

```
$ strace -e trace=connect ssh somehost -p 8081
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.1.1")}, 16) = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(8081), sin_addr=inet_addr(<host ip address>)}, 16) = 0
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh"}, 110) = 0
```

The lines you need are those with the `sa_family=AF_INET`.

Comment: Beware that `strace` has a huge overhead and is not recommended on production systems: http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2014-05-11/strace-wow-much-syscall.html

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your iptables rules to log traffic, and see exactly what traffic was being sent at the time you ran a given program. This won't work well on a busy system, as it doesn't actually tell you which program sent which traffic, but on a light load, you should be able to piece together what's happening.

Example for input and output:

```
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "INPUT:DROP:" --log-level 6
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "OUTPUT:DROP:" --log-level 6
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
```

There are a lot more options and features if you want to get more complex, too.

Comment: Nice suggestion. However, the `strace` command gave me immediate and by default filtered output, so that worked better in this case. Thanks for the answer, though.